# Get number of rows for each value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning pandas and I don't know how to approach this exercise. Given a dataframe: I need to know the number of sales that have been made for each region and the type of item that has been sold.

[image: Dataframe]

I understand that the number of sales is each row of the dataframe. For more complexity I have to solve the problem with a single line of code and using pivot_table.

How can I do it?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Region','Item']).size()`?

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang I must do it with pivot_table

Comment: `pivot_table` is essentially `groupby` then unstack: `df.pivot_table(index='Region', 'columns='item', values='Units', aggfunc='sum')`. Use `aggfunc='size'` if it fits you better.

Answer (score 0):

As Quan Hoang tell at comment. All I need to do is use
`df.groupby(['Region','Item']).size()` or `df.pivot_table(index='Region', 'columns='item', values='Units', aggfunc='sum')`